# listview onitemclick is not working in dialog inside android fragments

Tags: android, listview, fragment, onitemclicklistener

Im using fragments and in that i have used a dialog and populated a custom listview now I wanted to get the item click in the listview. which is not giving any response when i did like this below.
        please check someone.

```
     iv_fav_list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_fav_country_list);

                    lv_custom_list_fav_con = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.list_fav_country);
                    CFLA = new CustomFavCountryListAdapter(countryList, CountryActivityFragment.this.getActivity());
                    lv_custom_list_fav_con.setAdapter(CFLA);
                    dialog.show();
                    lv_custom_list_fav_con.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                            Toast.makeText(CountryActivityFragment.this.getActivity(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    });

                }
            });
```

the adapter class is

```
 ArrayList<Country> mCountryList;
    Context mContext;
    int position;
    Country cnt;
    OnDialogListClickListener mlistener;

    public interface OnDialogListClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public CustomFavCountryListAdapter(ArrayList<Country> countryList, Context context, OnDialogListClickListener listener) {

        this.mCountryList = countryList;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mlistener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCountryList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {

        return mCountryList.get(i);

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return mCountryList.get(i).getCountryID();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, final ViewGroup viewGroup) {


        position = i;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_fav_country_list, viewGroup,
                false);
        TextView tv_fav_con_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_custom_fav_country_name);
        tv_fav_con_name.setText(mCountryList.get(i).getCountryName());

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mlistener.onItemClick(position);
            }
        });

        convertView.setTag(mCountryList.get(i).getCountryName());
        return convertView;
    }


}
```

Comment: did your debugged your code on click listener?

Comment: nope, this is not even responding there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an interface in adapter

```
public interface OnDialogListClickListener {
    void onItemClick(Country item);
}
```

Pass this interface as parameter through adapter constructor and set as `setOnClickListener` of view that inflate in `getView` method in adapter.

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, final ViewGroup viewGroup) {


    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_fav_country_list, viewGroup,
            false);

    Country country = mCountryList.get(i);
    TextView tv_fav_con_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_custom_fav_country_name);
    tv_fav_con_name.setText(country.getCountryName());

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mlistener.onItemClick(country);
        }
    });

    convertView.setTag(country.getCountryName());
    return convertView;
}
```

Implement this interface in fragment.

```
private CustomFavCountryListAdapter.OnDialogListClickListener onDialogListClickListener = new CustomFavCountryListAdapter.OnDialogListClickListener () {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(Country item) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), country.getCountryName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Create adapter like this.

```
CFLA = new CustomFavCountryListAdapter(countryList, CountryActivityFragment.this.getActivity(), onDialogListClickListener);
```

Comment: but this gives always same list item, i need it to be dynamic

Comment: Can you post adapter class?

Comment: but this gives always same item, i need to get a dynamic item from the list

Comment: Change this ´mlistener.onItemClick(position);´ to ´mlistener.onItemClick(i);´ otherwise when you click it passes to listener same position because position is global variable and returns position of las item.

Comment: but mlistener.onItemClick(i) is in inner class right?,